# Java String to byteArray conversion issue

Tags: java, string, arrays

I am trying to encode/decode a `ByteArray` to `String`, but input/output are not matching. Am I doing something wrong?

```
System.out.println(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHexString(by));
String s = new String(by, Charsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHexString(s.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8)));
```

The output is:

```
130021000061f8f0001a
130021000061efbfbd
```

Complete code:

```
String[] arr = {"13", "00", "21", "00", "00", "61", "F8", "F0", "00", "1A"};        
byte[] by = new byte[arr.length];

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    by[i] = (byte)(Integer.parseInt(arr[i],16) & 0xff); 
}

System.out.println(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHexString(by));

String s = new String(by, Charsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHexString(s.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8)));
```

Comment: What were you originally trying to achieve?

Comment: @biziclop I am receiving a 10 byte string, first 3 bytes represent number1, next two represents number2, next byte represents number3 and remaining 4 bytes represent number 4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that `f8f0001a` isn't a valid UTF-8 byte sequence.

First of all, the `f8` opening byte denotes a 5 byte sequence and you've only got four. Secondly, `f8` can only be followed by a byte of `8x`, `9x`, `ax` or `bx` form.

Therefore it gets replaced with a `unicode replacement character (U+FFFD)`, whose byte sequence in UTF-8 is `efbfbd`.

And there (rightly) is no guarantee that the conversion of an invalid byte sequence to and from a string will result in the same byte sequence. (Note that even with two, seemingly identical strings, you might get different bytes representing them in Unicode, see [Unicode equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence). )

The moral of the story is: if you want to represent bytes, don't convert them to characters, and if you want to represent text, don't use byte arrays.

Answer (score 3):

My UTF-8 is a bit rusty :-), but the sequence `F8 F0` is imho not a valid utf-8 encoding.

Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8#Description.

Answer (score 2):

When you build the [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) from the array of bytes, the bytes are decoded.

Since the bytes from your code does not represent valid characters, the bytes that finally composes the [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) are not the same your passed as parameter.

> [public String(byte[] bytes)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-)
>
> Constructs a new `String` by decoding the
>   specified array of bytes using the platform's default charset. The
>   length of the new `String` is a function of the charset, and hence may
>   not be equal to the length of the byte array.
>
> The behavior of this
>   constructor when the given bytes are not valid in the default charset
>   is unspecified. The [`CharsetDecoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) class should be used when more
>   control over the decoding process is required.